# How to get values from Arraylist?

Tags: java

Already values in another java class arraylist, now i need to get those values from arraylist in another java class ?

How to get those vlaues from another java class arraylist?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hm? How about rephrasing your question? This is not clear.
Any examples?

Comment: Sorry Padma, there is not enough detail in your question to begin to help. Perhaps some progress could be made if you posted the code that you've written so far, or a simple illustration of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can expose the ArrayList as a public member of your class, but often it is better to expose a more restricted interface so that users of your class cannot for example modify the contents of the ArrayList when you only wanted to allow them read access.

```
public List<T> getList() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(yourlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've read this correctly (unlikely) you have an array list contained within one class. You can either expose the array list via an accessor:

```
public ArrayList getArrayList() {
   return list;
}
```

but that exposes your whole list to clients, so another option is to expose suitable methods for accessing it e.g.

```
public Object get(int i) {
   return list.get(i);
}
```

(you'd likely need a similar method to expose the length)

Comment: That's how I read it. Then you can add an ArrayList parameter to your 2nd class constructor to access it, perhaps. Or call one of the methods in some way above.

Comment: You should return the List interface instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: @Steve - It should probably be a generic as well, but I've deliberately left this as simple as possible for the benefit of the questioner. Is the above why this was downvoted ?